# JS Date out of Week

Tags: javascript, date

I have this small piece of code builded (with the help from many SO threads), it worked fine in the past 2 years but in 2018 it interprets the first week wrongly.

```js
function getDateOutWeek(week, year, lastDay) {
    var d = new Date(year, 0, 1 + (week) * 7);
    var day = d.getDay();
    var firstDay = d.getDate() - day + (day === 0 ? -6 : 1); // adjust when day is sunday

    if (!lastDay) {
        alert(new Date(d.setDate(firstDay)).toDateString());
    } else {
        alert(new Date(d.setDate(firstDay + 6)).toDateString());
    }

}

getDateOutWeek("1", "2018");
```

It returns 08.01.2018 but should return 01.01.2018.
The occurs already in the first line there it `calculate 1 + (week) * 7 = 8`. I cant figure out how to get the correct value here.

Comment: What's wrong with the output? Jan 08, 2018, is a Monday, like the output says. What are you expecting to see?

Comment: It should be Jan 1, 2018. Cause Jan 08,2018 is the second week

Comment: why `1 + (week)` ?

Comment: Why does your function expect 3 parameters, and you only call it with 2 parameters?

Comment: @KobyDouek the third one is If I want to get the last day of the week.

Comment: Note that this does not follow the ISO 8601 scheme for week numbering.

Comment: @RobG you know an good framework free way to follow it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why did you add 1 to your week?
the below code works fine

```js
function getDateOutWeek(week, year, lastDay) {
    var d = new Date(year, 0, week* 7);
    var day = d.getDay();
    var firstDay = d.getDate() - day + (day === 0 ? -6 : 1); // adjust when day is sunday

    if (!lastDay) {
        alert(new Date(d.setDate(firstDay)).toDateString());
    } else {
        alert(new Date(d.setDate(firstDay + 6)).toDateString());
    }

}

getDateOutWeek("1", "2018")
```

Comment: Wait I had for sure an reason for the + 1. It cant be that easy :D Seriously at the moment this will do the trick, I just cant believe I inserted a +1 witouth a reason.

Comment: The code above still works for 2013 (returning Mon, January 7th), so probably not a good reason ;) Maybe because you already included the +1 in `day === 0 ? -6 : 1`

Comment: may be you would have considered calling first week as 0th week, i am not sure

Comment: Could have been the reason @Stephan anyway this one fixed it ty